# React Bootstrap - Controlled Carousel does not scroll anymore

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I use React Bootstrap Carousel in my GatsbyJS project.

I have an issue with the controlled carousel because does not scroll anymore.

I use in a component that display 3 Carousel items.

```
const SimpleCarousel = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const items = [1, 2, 3]

  function handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    setIndex(selectedIndex)
  }

  return (
    <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
    >
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Carousel.Item key={`carousel-item-${item}`}>
            <h2>Title {item}</h2>
          </Carousel.Item>
        ))}
  )
}

export default SimpleCarousel;
```

I use activeIndex with a state and onSelect handler as in documentation, but the handler function is not called and the active index does not change.

It works with multiple `<Carousel.Item>` but not after a map.

Configuration :

- Windows 10
- node : 12.16.1
- react-bootstrap : 1.6.1
- boostrap : 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sandbox and copy pasted your code. I noticed that the closing tag of carousel is missing: `</Carousel>`. Maybe this is the problem and you don't get a proper error somehow?

Anyway the sandbox is working just with copy/pasing your code. The items are changing after few seconds. The onSelect handler is called every time: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-monad-hv83g4

This is react-boostrap v2 though. I can't manage to add an older version of it as dependency (v1). So when then sandbox is working and yours are not, I assume it's a react-bootstrap 1.6.1 specific issue.

Comment: I forgot to add the closing tag in my example code... I will have to upgrade to version 2. Thanks for your answer !